# Export to CSV only returning string length

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I'm trying to get this script to export to a CSV file, it only lists the string length and not the emails i am trying to pull.

```
Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like 'Security Group'} | 
    Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser -Properties Mail |
    select -ExpandProperty Mail |
    Export-Csv -NoType MyCSVfile1.csv
```

Comment: Wow, I feel like a dummy.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Export-Csv` expects to receive an object, you've given it a string so it's giving you the properties of that string in the output file (that is, `Length`).

Drop `-ExpandProperty` and it will be fine.

```
Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like 'Security Group'} |
    Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser -Properties Mail |
    Select Mail |
    Export-Csv -NoType MyCSVfile1.csv
```

Comment: Otherwise just wirte the value list to a file: `... | Select -Expand Mail | Set-Content MyCSVfile1.csv`.