# Export-Csv emits Length and not values

Tags: powershell

I want to read a CSV file and output a CSV file with only one (1) field. I have tried to create a concise example.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> Get-Content .\t.csv
field1,field2,field3
1,2,3
4,55,6
7,888,9

PS C:\src\powershell> Import-Csv -Path .\t.csv | `
>>     ForEach-Object {
>> $_.field2 `
>>     } | `
>>     Export-Csv -Path .\x.csv -NoTypeInformation
>>
```

The problem is that the Length of field2 is written to the exported CSV file. I want the field header to be "field2" and the values to be the value from the original CSV file. Also, I only want quotes where they are required; not everywhere.

I have read [Export-CSV exports length but not name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450616/export-csv-exports-length-but-not-name) and [Export to CSV only returning string length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875634/export-to-csv-only-returning-string-length). But these do not seem to address producing an actual CSV file with a header and one field value.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> get-content .\x.csv
"Length"
"1"
"2"
"3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV object uses *note properties* in each row to store its fields so we'll need to filter each row object and leave just the field(s) we want using `Select-Object` cmdlet (alias: `select`), which processes the entire CSV object at once:

```ps
Import-Csv 1.csv | select field2 | Export-Csv 2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note, there's no need to escape the end of line if it ends with `|`, `{`, `(`, or `,`.
It's possible to specify several fields: `select field2, field3`.

---

To strip unneeded doublequotes, general multi-field case:

```ps
Import-Csv 1.csv |
    select field2 |
    %{
        $_.PSObject.Properties | %{ $_.value = $_.value -replace '"', [char]1 }
        $_
    } |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    %{ $_ -replace '"(\S*?)"', '$1' -replace '\x01', '""' } |
    Out-File 2.csv -Encoding ascii
```

Simplified one-field case:

```ps
Import-Csv 1.csv |
    select field2 |
    %{
        $_.field2 = $_.field2 -replace '"', [char]1
        $_
    } |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    %{ $_ -replace '"(\S*?)"', '$1' -replace '\x01', '""' } |
    Out-File 2.csv -Encoding ascii
```

A tricky case of embedded quotes inside a field was solved by temporary replacing them with a control character code 01 (there are just a few that can be used in a typical non-broken text file: 09/tab, 0A/line feed, 0D/carriage return).

Comment: I do believe you have it... for one (1) field. It would require some cycles to convert this into a full solution for generic CSV usage. It really should be that Powershell provides switches to control quoting. Some may want or need every field quoted. I would like to see quoting omitted unless the field contains quote characters or the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

As per WOxxOm's response, `Select-Object` is best way to select only field from an input and pipe to output.

Regarding the quote marks, this is a known (and frustrating) issue with PowerShell. Specifying `,` as the delimiter did not help.
I have gotten round it by using `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Foreach-Object` replacements. THe replacements will need to be more complex if your data contains quote marks.

```
Import-Csv .\1.csv |
Select-Object field2 |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '"',''} |
Out-File .\2.csv
```

Comment: Thanks @gms0ulman. This does work, but, as you mentioned, the quote removal will not work for many situations.